# Remove USB dual boot Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows-7

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10.
I installed Ubuntu 12.10 onto my USB.
But on boot, even though my USB is not in the computer, I still have the option to select Ubuntu. When I select Ubuntu, I can not boot into it as the USB is not in.

How can I remove/uninstall Ubuntu 12.10 from my computer completely?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Ubuntu boot loader, you have to boot from the Windows 7 Installation Disk (or a bootable USB drive) and click on the `Repair your computer` link in the bottom left corner. After this, select your Windows 7 installation and click `Next`, then select `Command prompt`. After this, type the following commands:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

This will restore the Windows 7 boot loader and remove Ubuntu from startup.

To completely remove the Ubuntu installation, you can remove the partitions that Ubuntu used with Disk Management. To open it, open the start menu and type `diskmgmt.msc` and hit enter. This will show all the partitions on your disks, and you can remove the ones that were used by Ubuntu (they have no filesystem recognized) and create new partitions for Windows if necessary (or extend the current partitions). [Here's](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-manage-your-disks-using-disk-management-utility) a small tutorial on Disk Management.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect your USB disk
2. Boot on your Ubuntu
3. Install and run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu)
4. When asked if the disk is removable, answer `Yes`
5. Click the `Recommended Repair` button